# Sorting an array according to defined order

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, splice

I am trying to sort all items in the array `items` to follow the order specified in `string`. I am trying to get `results` to be

```
["first", "second", "third", "last"]
```

after sorting. The starting array has a randomized order.

```js
var string = "first;second;third;last",
    items = ["third", "first", "last", "second"],
    result = [],
    lastpos = 0,
    lastinsert = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
 var mypos = string.indexOf(items[i]),
     insertat;
 if (mypos > lastpos) {
  insertat = lastinsert
 } else {
  insertat = lastinsert + 1
 }
 result.splice(insertat, 0, items[i]);
 lastpos = mypos;
}

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result);
```

```html
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

I am *not* asking to have textual analysis to sort the array. The array should simply follow the order of the items in the variable `string`.

Comment: i have no idea what youre asking

Comment: Same.  Can you re-write your snippet using names that would make sense?  Sorry, it's just hard to keep track of `a:first`, `b:last`, etc.

Comment: It's still confusing, I'm afraid.  Does `items` contain exactly the same set of values as `string`?  If so, why bother sorting at all?  Just manipulate `string`.  BTW, Javascript has a `sort` method on `Array.prototype`.

Comment: In other words, would `result = string.split(';')` not be sufficient?

Comment: @ScottSauyet Yes, `items` and `string` will contain the same values. Before this sorting actually happens, the string is taken as input, then the array is made using it. Because of the way that step works, the script "prefers" certain types of values and process them first, they will be on top of the array. I will then have to reorder the array.

Comment: Then is this all you need?: `var result = string.split(';');` You can ignore `items`, the indices, the loop, everything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are asking more about the process to sort an array based on the values / indexes of another.  Otherwise, there would be no reason to sort.

You can try using [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) with something like this:

```
var string = "first;second;third;last".split(';'),
    items = ["third", "first", "last", "second"],
    result = [];

result = items.sort(function(a,b) {
    return string.indexOf(a) - string.indexOf(b) 
});

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result);
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3647nd99/) example.

--edit--

As per the comments, this should be more performance-friendly:

```
var string = "first;second;third;last".split(';'),
    stringHash = {},
    items = ["third", "first", "last", "second"],
    result = [];    

for (var i = 0, j = string.length; i < j; i++) {
    stringHash[string[i]] = i;
}

result = items.sort(function(a,b) {
    return stringHash[a] - stringHash[b];
});

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result);
```

You will be adding in an extra step, so if the original arrays are small it may not be worth it.  If the arrays are larger, though, this will perform significantly better.

Comment: Keep in mind, though, that if your actual arrays are really big, this will be *extremely* slow.

Comment: Is there an alternative that performs better with large arrays? I guess not, since this is a custom sorting algorithm.

Comment: The performance hit comes from `Array.prototype.indexOf()`, not the actual sorting itself.  I'll edit my answer with another way to solve it that is more performance-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm understanding correctly, but if your goal is simply to get an array of those elements in the original order, it would be simplest just to re-split from the original string:

```js
var string = "a:test;a:second;b:third;a:last";
var result = string.split(';');
```

Or is there some transformation being performed on the data that's not depicted in the snippet there, that actually requires to you un-sort the existing array elements?